# Finding such a $A \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming

I am using Grégroire Allaire's *Analyse numérique et optimisation* (*Numerical analysis and optimization*) for a project on the simplex algorithm. I would like to use at one point the result of an exercise he leaves to the reader (but isn't supposed to use his material). It reads as follows:

> Find $A \in M_{m,n}(\mathbb{R})$ and $b \in \mathbb{R}^m$ such that $X=\left\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R}^n, Ax=b, x\geq 0 \right \rbrace $ is the unit cube $[0,1]^{n-m}$ in the affine vector space defined by $Ax=b$.

I tried to fool around with it, but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's unclear what exactly the question is asking; perhaps there's an issue with your translation.  Did you mean that you're looking for $A,b$ such that $X$ **is** the unit cube $[0,1]^n$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I was asking! Sorry for the delay @Omnomnomnom...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unit cube in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is defined by the linear system of inequalities
$$
\begin{matrix}
x & & \geq 0 \\
  & y & \geq 0 \\
x & & \leq 1 \\
 & y & \leq 1
\end{matrix}
$$

This looks like the form $Ax \geq b$, rather than $Ax = b$. So add in the slack variables $s, t$ to convert to standard form:
$$
\begin{matrix}
x & & & & \geq 0 \\
  & y & & & \geq 0 \\
 &  & s& & \geq 0 \\
 &  & & t& \geq 0 \\
x &+ &s & &  = 1 \\
 & y & + & t &= 1
\end{matrix}
$$
And so we have four variables, and we are in the form $Ax = b$, $x \geq 0$ with the matrices $A, b$ being
$$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}, \quad b = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

You can now check that the solution space of $Ax = b$ has dimension 2, and once you impose the constraint that $x \geq 0$, it becomes a square.

Hopefully this makes it clear how to extend to higher dimensions.

Comment: thank you very much! Unfortuanately, I cannot upvote you (too little reputation), but your answer makes much sense and is of much help nonetheless!